# VideoPlayback with Object recognition vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

i'm trying to play video on real object target and i'm using the render frame function from the sample which play the video on an image , but when use it on real object it doesnt show the video though the video can be played and you can hear the sound of the video .

```
     public void renderFrame(State state, float[] projectionMatrix)
{
    // Renders video background replacing Renderer.DrawVideoBackground()
    mSampleAppRenderer.renderVideoBackground();

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if(tappingProjectionMatrix == null)
    {
        tappingProjectionMatrix = new Matrix44F();
        tappingProjectionMatrix.setData(projectionMatrix);
    }

    // Did we find any trackables this frame?
    for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++)
    {
        // Get the trackable:
        TrackableResult trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);

        ObjectTarget imageTarget = (ObjectTarget) trackableResult
            .getTrackable();

        int currentTarget;

        // We store the modelview matrix to be used later by the tap
        // calculation
        if (imageTarget.getName().compareTo("grafik1") == 0)
            currentTarget = VideoPlayback.STONES;
        else
            currentTarget = VideoPlayback.CHIPS;

        modelViewMatrix[currentTarget] = Tool
            .convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose());

        isTracking[currentTarget] = true;

        targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget] = imageTarget.getSize();


        // If the movie is ready to start playing or it has reached the end
        // of playback we render the keyframe
        if ((currentStatus[currentTarget] == VideoPlayerHelper.MEDIA_STATE.READY)
            || (currentStatus[currentTarget] == VideoPlayerHelper.MEDIA_STATE.REACHED_END)
            || (currentStatus[currentTarget] == VideoPlayerHelper.MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY)
            || (currentStatus[currentTarget] == VideoPlayerHelper.MEDIA_STATE.ERROR)) {


            float[] modelViewMatrixKeyframe = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(
                    trackableResult.getPose()).getData();


            float[] modelViewProjectionKeyframe = new float[16];

            Log.d("size ", "" + targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget].getData()[0] + "  heigt" + targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget].getData()[1] );

            Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrixKeyframe, 0,
                    0.1235f,
                    0.1235f,
                    0.1235f);

            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionKeyframe, 0,
                    projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrixKeyframe, 0);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(keyframeShaderID);

            // Prepare for rendering the keyframe
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(keyframeVertexHandle, 3,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, quadVertices);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(keyframeTexCoordHandle, 2,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, quadTexCoords);

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(keyframeVertexHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(keyframeTexCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

            // The first loaded texture from the assets folder is the
            // keyframe
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    mTextures.get(0).mTextureID[0]);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(keyframeMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false,
                    modelViewProjectionKeyframe, 0);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(keyframeTexSampler2DHandle, 0);

            // Render
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_QUAD_INDEX,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(keyframeVertexHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(keyframeTexCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
        }

        SampleUtils.checkGLError("VideoPlayback renderFrame");
    }

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    Renderer.getInstance().end();

}
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really relate to an error in your code, although generally speaking it looks ok. I'll try to give you the correct strategy to advance.

If you hear the video but do not see it, it is probably either some OpenGL error (the video is really not drawing), or position problem (the video is drawing, but in such a position / size that you cannot see it).

First check the log for gl errors - it should be easier to detect (you are using `checkGLError`). If you see errors, try to isolate the cause- maybe something is not setup properly for getting the video texture or there is some shader error.

If there are no errors - try to debug the location (matrix position and size). You can try to manually set the size and the axis in order to get to the state you can see something.

Good luck...